# Canon AE1 Program rewind crank screw hole, what size?

Tags: canon, 35mm

I have a Canon AE-1 Program with a missing rewind crank. Can't find a replacement anywhere online, thinking of trying to rig something on my own. There is a threaded hole in the center of the ASA selector where the crank would go. What size bolt/thread would fit in there?

Also, in case I just want to buy a whole bunch of sizes to test, do Canon cameras use metric or imperial bolts?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i went ahead and ordered a bunch of metric machine screw sizes in the hopes that one would work.

Turns out a `3mm X .5mm` will fit nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find multiple listings for the part if you search your favorite auction site for "Canon rewind". Parts for the AE-1 appear to be fairly expensive, so it might be cheaper to purchase a broken camera. The rewind crank from another model *may* be compatible, since many of them look the same.

Some camera stores have junk piles you can look through.

If you still wish to fashion a makeshift crank, you can measure the diameter with calipers. However, it's unlikely you'll find any camera-compatible parts at hardware stores, aside from 1/4" screws, which fit tripod mounts.

The following resources may be helpful, though they do not state part sizes.

- ManualsLib: [Canon AE-1 Service Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/704000/Canon-Ae-1.html)
- iFixit: [Canon AE-1 Film Rewind Crank Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Canon+AE-1+Film+Rewind+Crank+Replacement/6876)

Comment: For OQ: Here's a current eBay UK listing for AE-1 Program crank: https://www.ebay.ie/itm/CANON-AE-1-PROGRAM-FILM-REWIND-KNOB-AND-CRANK-BLACK/133150492897?hash=item1f006348e1:g:F44AAOSwlHJdYVW7

Answer (score 1):

Should be metric.  To be safe, take the camera with you when you go to the hardware store.